# Show that $f_n(\cdot):[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R$, $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x^n)$ is simple convergent, but not uniform convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Not sure if I solved this correctly.

> Show that $$f_n(\cdot):[0,1]\rightarrow \Bbb R$$ $$f_n(x)=x^n(1-x^n)$$
>   is simple convergent, but not uniform convergent.

How I solved it:

$(1)$ $\forall x \in \Bbb R$, $\exists \lim_{n\to \infty}x^n(1-x^n)=0$ $\to$ the series is simple convergent;

$(2)$(I just chose a number in [0,1] that does not converge to 0)
If $x=\frac 12$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 12)^n(1-(\frac 12)^n)=-\infty $ $\to$ the series is not uniform convergent;
I think (1) is correct but I am not sure about (2).

Comment: The (1) is correct, but then the result of the (2) is obviously false as it directly contradicts the (1)

Comment: Yes I just noticed. I edited (1), does it make any sense now?

Comment: For (2), compute $f_n \bigl((1/2)^{1/n}\bigr)$.

Comment: In the (1) you prove that the series is simple (pointwise) convergent, in the (2) you prove that the series is NOT simple (pointwise) convergent. Do you realize the mistake in the limit ?

Comment: @T_O I have similar examples solved in class that are solved just like I wrote there, any idea how to how it is not uniform convergent? ; DavidMitra doesn't that equal 0?

Comment: $f_n((1/2)^{1/n})= (1/2)(1-1/2)=1/4$ for each $n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I don't think that is correct because if I have $x=(\frac 12)^\frac1n$ then that will be $((\frac 12)^\frac 1n)^n$ which is $(2^{-1/n})^n$ and it will eqal $0$ in the end.

Comment: ? $((1/2)^{1/n})^n=(1/2)^{(1/n)\cdot n}=(1/2)^1=1/2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Sorry, that is correct. Wolfram trolled me for a moment :)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Answer from comments</sup>

In   (1) you prove that the series is simple (pointwise) convergent, in the (2) you prove that the series is NOT simple (pointwise) convergent. Do you realize the mistake in the limit ? -- [T_O](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724623/show-that-f-n-cdot0-1-rightarrow-bbb-r-f-nx-xn1-xn-is-simple-co#comment1514009_724623)

For part (2), calculate $f_n((1/2)^{1/n})= (1/2)(1-1/2)=1/4$. -- [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724623/show-that-f-n-cdot0-1-rightarrow-bbb-r-f-nx-xn1-xn-is-simple-co#comment1514026_724623)

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac 12)^n(1-(\frac 12)^n)$ is not tending to $-\infty$ because if you take a closer look $(\frac 12)^n$ is tending to $0$ as $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ and so does$(1-(\frac 12)^n)$. So basically the limit tends to $0$.

Comment: Please enclose formatting between $ signs

Comment: Actually I am new thanks for the help